# How to use an xml file for image folder?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, image

I am really new to WPF and XML. I have an images folder and an xml file (there is my image folder's name and image names in my XML file). How can I call my images from the file through xml and make a list with them?

Thank you. (My image folder is placed on my desktop and and also in Project Debug folder.)

XML Sample

```
<Item>
    <Title>
        Image 1
    </Title>
    <Image>
        <Image FolderName="Images">1.jpg</Image>
    </Image>
</Item>
```

Where I get stuck.

```
void LoadImages()
    {
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("images.xml");

        picList = new List<Picture>();

        var pics = (from item in xml.Descendants("Item")
                     select new Picture
                     {

                         Title = (string)item.Element("Title").Value,
                         Img = (BitmapImage(?????????))item.Element("Image")???

                     }).ToList();

        foreach (var item in pics)
        {
            picList.Add(item);
        }

        imgList.ItemsSource = picList;
    }
```

My Picture Class

```
     public class Picture
    {

        public BitmapImage Img { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean with "*call my images*". You would obviously have to read the XML file, construct a file path from an `<Image>` element, and then load e.g. a BitmapImage from an Uri for the file path.

Comment: I can do it like this. I just wanna do it through XML file. Just with image names. picList = new List<Picture>();
            picList.Add(new Picture()
            {
                Img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Proje\Images\1.jpg")),
                Title = "No 1",
            });
            imgList.ItemsSource = picList;

Comment: I am sorry I dont know how to post my code in a proper way. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the XML structure to something like shown below, with only a single `<Image>` element per `<Item>`.

```
<Item>
    <Title>Image 1</Title>
    <Image FolderName="Images">1.jpg</Image>
</Item>
```

Then this should work with relative image paths:

```
public void LoadImages()
{
    imgList.ItemsSource = XDocument.Load("images.xml")
        .Descendants("Item")
        .Select(item =>
    {
        var title = item.Element("Title").Value;
        var folder = item.Element("Image").Attribute("FolderName").Value;
        var file = item.Element("Image").Value;
        var path = Path.Combine(folder, file);

        return new Picture
        {
            Title = title,
            Img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative))
        };
    });
}
```

In case you need absolute file paths, you may add the images root folder to the `Path.Combine` call, and remove `UriKind.Relative`.

You should also declare the Picture class like shown below for greater flexibility in the range of types you can pass to the `Img` property:

```
public class Picture
{
    public ImageSource Img { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```